# Trig Question - Sum of angles

Tags: trigonometry

Problem: Let $r$ and $s$ be the two solutions to the equation $x^2 - 2003x + 2004 = 0.$ Determine $\arctan r + \arctan s,$ in radians.

I know the sum of the roots is $2003$ and their product is $2004$, but I'm not sure how that helps. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Hint: $\tan(a+b) = (\tan a+\tan b)/(1-\tan a\tan b)$. What happens if $a=\arctan r$ and $b=\arctan s$?

Comment: I got $3/4\pi$ and it was correct. Thanks so much!